# Visual Studio crashes when starting to debug stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I am trying to debug a stored procedure on SQL Server 2008 with Visual Studio Team System 2008.

When right-clicking the stored procedure in the Server Explorer and clicking on "Step Into", the IDE simply crashes without any error message.

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: With each new release of Visual Studio, we spend a few days trying to get stored procedure debugging to work.  We never succeed.  I think it's vaporware.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the debug functionality in Management Studio instead of in Visual Studio.

Comment: Does debugging in SSMS work for you?  One of my colleagues said it used to work in 2004, but it's been broken since, whatever we try.  It would be very useful for us.

Comment: Where can I find this? The SQL server book I have only mentions debugging in Visual Studio. Also, this manual mentions debugging in SSMS, but actually describes debugging in Visual Studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241871.aspx

Comment: I don't use the debugging feature (in fact I remove it from the toolbar, because it looks too much like the execute button from Query Analyzer, and I would try to start debugging sessions way too often).  There are restrictions, for example I think you need to use Windows auth and have sufficient privileges on the remote machine (should be fine for local debugging against a local instance).

Note that this is in SSMS 2008 only.  These URLs might help Adrian:

http://is.gd/4xF0m

http://is.gd/4xF54